# openni2_tracker problems

Tags: ros, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I am currently using ROS Groovy and I recently decided to move from openNI 1.5 to openNI 2.

I tried openni2_tracker and managed to make it work, but I have two problems :

- The node needs to find data file ./Nite2/s.dat, so it's not working if you don't run it from a specific directory. Which means you can not put it in a launch file you want to run from anywhere on your system. Is it a normal thing ?
- It's not possible to launch the script openni2.launch (with all sensor driver) and openni2_tracker at the same time. It's a problem for me because I would like to run other nodes using the camera data at the same time than openni2_tracker.

Does someone have some information ?

Thanks,

Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89381/openni2_tracker-problems/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sparksmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/12901/sparksmith/) on 2014-03-06**:
hello, sorry for bothering you but how did you run openni2_tracker - because i have a build issue with orocos_kdl ?

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2014-09-18**:
I have the same problem with ROS Hydro. It is not possible to use openni2.launch togheter with openni2_tracker

**Comment by [manideep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27106/manideep/) on 2016-06-08**:
i am using kinect with windows 10, facing same problem.Please can any one solve this error.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go into the folder where Nite2/s.dat.
In my case I installed nite2 in my home directory, so I ran openni2_tracker node from inside this path:

~/NiTE-2.0.0/Redist/

Therefore, s.dat is locate here "~/NiTE-2.0.0/Redist/NiTE2/s.dat"
Openni2_tracker will work in that way. It's kinda lame, though. There's gotta be a better way to have the ros node understand the path. The path is allegedly provided through the CMakelist of the openni2_tracker package, but that does not seem to fully work. You must figure how to provide the path in correctly in your CMakeList file.

---

Originally posted by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) with karma: 803 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0